# getting input in java throws exception

Tags: java

```
DataInput in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
System.out.println("What is your name");
String name = in.readLine();
```

The error says "Unhandled IO Exception". What's wrong with this code ?

Comment: `readLine` throws a checked exception

Comment: @WinCoder I gave a quick explanation of checked and unchecked exception  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423700/how-to-create-a-custom-exception-type-in-java/8423743#8423743).

Answer (score 4):

> Unhandled IO Exception

either catch `IOException` or declare it to throw, `readLine()` declares that it could throw this exception so your code need to handle/throw it

Answer (score 2):

You must surround the call to `in.readLine ()` with a `try/catch`.

```
DataInput in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
System.out.println("What is your name");

try {
    String name = in.readLine();
} catch (IOException ioex) {
    // Handle exception accordingly
}
```

Or you could add a `trows IOException` clause to your method signature, which means the calling method will have to handle the exception (with the `try/catch` block).

As per the [Javadoc entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29), the the `readLine ()` method is deprecated, and you should use a `BufferedReader` instead.

Comment: why would a console interaction method throw an exception ?

Comment: @WinCoder if an I/O error occurs while reading the stream, an `IOException` will be thrown, with the available details in the exception object.

Comment: Could be any number of reasons.  Ultimately, it doesn't matter though, because the method is declared as `throws IOException`, you are required, one way or another, to handle the exception, whether by catching it or by declaring your method `throws IOException` (or some superclass of `IOException`)

Answer (score 1):

This method `readLine()` throws  `IOException` that is a checked Exception. So You have two options catch it and handle it and/or in method declaration add `throws` keyword

Example:

```
public void throwsMethod() throws IOException{
  DataInput in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
  System.out.println("What is your name");
  String name = in.readLine();
  .
  .
}

public void handleMethod(){
  DataInput in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
  System.out.println("What is your name");
  String name=null;
  try{
    name = in.readLine();
  }catch(IOException){
   //do something here
  }
  .
  .
}
```

For more information read this oracle article [Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

readLine() throws IOException which is checked exception should be either thrown or handled at compile time see [**Oracle documentation**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)