# Correct Java Exception for a malfomed string

Tags: java, exception

I have a method that should only accept strings of a certain format. When the format is invalid, I want to throw an Exception. I'm quite new to Java, so am not sure what the correct type of exception to use here is. I found there is a IllegalFormatException, which based on the name sounds right, though [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IllegalFormatException.html) make me rather unsure about this. What is the correct Exception class to use here?

The method in question is the constructor of a PropertyId class, which takes one string argument, which should match '/^p[1-9][0-9]*$/i'. It should behave essentially the same as [this equivalent in Python](https://github.com/JeroenDeDauw/WikibaseDataModelPython/blob/3ced52745a4a28ae47d1901781994d06d29c83fa/wikibase/dataModel/entity/property_id.py).

I'd prefer using an Exception provided by the standard library, unless there really is none that is appropriate, or it is generally agreed on that in my case a new Exception derivative should be created.

Comment: can you write your format?

Comment: IllegalArgumentException or an app-specific exception.

Comment: An argument for app-specific exception is that you get more control; Eclipse (IDE), for instance, will warn if your exception needs to be handled everywhere it is used. You don't get this feature with a runtime exception like IllegalFormatException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am with @TwoThe. [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) is the way to go. In fact, I actually don't think there should be much debate. This situation is exactly what IllegalArgumentException was made for.

IllegalFormatException is misleading for sure, but that (and its subclasses) is for a completely different case--when the format string you provide for [output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) is invalid.

Generating your own custom exceptions should only be done with great care. Only when you have a special case where no standard exceptions apply. That isn't true here, and you don't want your clients to have to deal with non-standard stuff unless absolutely necessary.

Remember, with great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: In addition you can always add a specific error description to the exception during construction.

Answer (score 3):

This appear reasonable to me, from the Javadoc for IllegalFormatException

> Unchecked exception thrown when a format string contains an illegal
>   syntax  or a format specifier that is incompatible with the given
>   arguments.  Only  explicit subtypes of this exception which correspond
>   to specific errors  should be instantiated.

As @BasvandenBroek points out, this is appropriate for String which contain format information, rather than checking the format of a String.

However, it may be that it's parent IllegalArgumentException is best.  NumberFormatException is close, but not approriate, and it's parent is also IAE.

Note: you can create your own sub-class of IllegalArgumentException

```
public class StringValidationFailedException extends IllegalArgumentException {
     public StringValidationFailedException(String message) {
          super(message);
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure, this looks like it specifically is about strings to be used to format something, i.e. %d, not about the format of a string in general.

Answer (score 2):

Try [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are many exceptions in Java, but it sounds like you may need a custom exception depending on what you mean by format. There are many examples of that on this site. Here are just two links.

[How to create a custom exception type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423700/how-to-create-a-custom-exception-type-in-java)

[How to define custom exception class in Java, the easiest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776327/how-to-define-custom-exception-class-in-java-the-easiest-way)