# What exception to throw when file is not properly formated/empty

Tags: java, exception

For example I've this file that should be formated like this:

```
PersonName
2,5,6,7,8,9
```

First line only has a name and from the second line onwards its all comma separated values.
Ending in a new line. For some reason I can't make a new empty line in code format.

Now lets say that those comma separated values will be copied into an `ArrayList` and then I check if the `ArrayList` is empty or not. If it is empty I've to throw an exception. My question is, what exception to throw here?

Something like (in pseudo code):

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

while(interator.hasCSV) {
// copy values to list
    Object obj = interator.next();
    list.add(obj);
}

if(list.isEmpty()) {
   // What exception to throw here?
   // It means there was a name in the file (first line) but then no csv values 
}
```

I hope I made myself clear otherwise just let me know and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423700/how-to-create-a-custom-exception-type-in-java

Comment: Propably create your own Exception class, like `my.pack.FileFormatException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as paxdiablo said you can create your own exception here is an example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423700/how-to-create-a-custom-exception-type-in-java)

```
class CheckListException extends Exception
{
      //Parameterless Constructor
      public CheckListException() {}

      //Constructor that accepts a message
      public CheckListException(List list)
      {
         super(list);
      }
 }
```

to use the exception

```
 try
 {
    if(list.isEmpty()) {
         // What exception to throw here?
         // It means there was a name in the file (first line) but then no csv values 
          throw new CheckListException();
    }
 }
 catch(CheckListException ex)
 {
      //Process message however you would like
 }
```

Comment: Nice one again. +1 From me :-)

Answer (score 3):

There's no requirement to use the standard ones defined in Java since you can create whatever ones you need.

While it looks like (from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)) the *closest* one in the standard set is probably `DataFormatException` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DataFormatException.html)), that's targeted to ZIP files.

Perhaps a better match would be [ParseException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html). If you wanted to use one of the more targeted standard ones, that would be the one I'd be looking to use (if you don't wish to create your own), or inherit from (if you do).

But keep in mind you can always inherit from the top-level Exception class if you're not overly concerned about where it is in the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for spending the time looking for a standard exception :) +1 given

Answer (score 2):

Create your own exception. For further details follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754315/how-to-create-our-own-exceptions-in-java)

```
if()//your condition
  /*create custom exeception*/
  throw new Exception("My custom exception");
}
```

**But this is one time exception**.

You have to follow the above link to create a new class for your custom exception to **reuse**.

Answer (score 2):

It would be normal to place all the code responsible for parsing the content of the file in its own method. Most parsers interleave reading from the input stream and examining what it has read. Such a method must declare that it `throws IOException`, because the parts of the method that read from the input stream can throw an `IOException`. The parsing method will be easier to use if parse errors are *also* indicated by throwing an `IOException`: a caller of the method can use one `catch` to handle all problems, if they are not interested in the details of the problems.

A caller of the method might however want to be able to distinguish between different kinds of problems. The caller might want to report different error messages for a missing file and for an incorrectly formatted file. To support this, you could create your own `InvalidFormatException` that `extends IOException` and throw that when there is a parse error.