# JAVA adjecency matrix null pointer

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, computer-science

I have a couple of errors in my code and need some help figuring out how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here are the errors:

symptom: java.lang.NullPointerException
at assignment4.AdjacencyGraph.getHighestDegreeNode(AdjacencyGraph.java:136)

symptom: java.lang.NullPointerException
at assignment4.AdjacencyGraph.addEdge(AdjacencyGraph.java:85)

IllegalStateForMatrix should be raised when calling getNumberOfEdges with 0 edges.

IllegalStateForMatrix should be called if getNumberOfEdges is called before createAdjacencyMatrix.

```
public class IllegalStateForMatrixException extends Exception {

public IllegalStateForMatrixException(String el) {
    super("Illegal call to "+el + " before the matrix was created (must call createAdjacencyMatrix)");
}
```

}

```
class AdjacencyGraph extends Graph {

private ArrayList nodes = new ArrayList();
private int noEdges = 0;
public int[][] adjM;

/**
 * Adjacency Matrix with integers.
 */
@Override
void createAdjacencyMatrix() {
    adjM = new int[nodes.size()][nodes.size()];
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            adjM[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Adds the node.
 *
 * @param nodeName
 */
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
void addNode(String nodeName) {
    nodes.add(nodeName);
}

/**
 * Adds the edge.
 *
 * @param fromNode
 * @param toNode
 * @param weight
 * @throws ElementNotFoundException
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
void addEdge(String fromNode, String toNode, int weight)
        throws ElementNotFoundException, IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    {
        try {
            int i;
            int j;
            for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
                if (nodes.get(i).equals(fromNode)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i == nodes.size()) {
                throw new ElementNotFoundException("Exception");
            }

            for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
                if (nodes.get(j).equals(toNode)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j == nodes.size()) {
                throw new ElementNotFoundException("Exception");
            }

            adjM[i][j] = weight;
            adjM[j][i] = weight;
            noEdges++;
        } 
        catch (ElementNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception found");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the number of nodes.
 *
 * @return number of nodes
 */
@Override
int getNumberOfNodes() {
    return nodes.size();
}

/**
 * Returns the number of edges
 *
 * @return number of edges
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
int getNumberOfEdges() throws IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    if (nodes.size() <= 0)
        throw new IllegalStateForMatrixException("Error");
    return noEdges;
}

/**
 * Returns the highest degree node.
 *
 * @return highest degree node.
 * @throws ElementNotFoundException
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
public String getHighestDegreeNode()
        throws ElementNotFoundException, IllegalStateForMatrixException {

    int i;
    int ansIndex = 0;
    int j;
    int ansCount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        int k = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            if (adjM[i][j] != -1) {
                k++;
            }
        }
        if (k > ansCount) {
            ansCount = k;
            ansIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return (String) nodes.get(ansIndex);
}

/**
 * Cost of the edge between nodes.
 *
 * @param fromNode
 * @param toNode
 * @return returns -1
 * @throws ElementNotFoundException
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
int costOfEdgeBetween(String fromNode, String toNode)
        throws ElementNotFoundException, IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    try {
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
            if (nodes.get(i).equals(fromNode)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == nodes.size()) {
            throw new ElementNotFoundException("Exception");
        }

        for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            if (nodes.get(j).equals(toNode)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == nodes.size()) {
            throw new ElementNotFoundException("Exception");
        }

        return adjM[i][j];
    } 
    catch (ElementNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception found");
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 *
 * @param fromName
 * @param toName
 * @return false
 * @throws ElementNotFoundException
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
boolean hasPathBetween(String fromName, String toName)
        throws ElementNotFoundException, IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    try {
        ArrayStack<Integer> st = new ArrayStack<Integer>();
        int[] visited = new int[nodes.size()];
        int i;
        int j;
        int start;
        int end;
        for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
            visited[i] = 0;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
            if (nodes.get(i).equals(fromName)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        start = i;

        for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            if (nodes.get(j).equals(toName)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        end = j;
        st.push(start);
        visited[start] = 1;
        while (st.isEmpty() != true) {
            i = st.pop();
            if (i == end) {
                return true;
            }
            for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
                if (adjM[i][j] != -1 && visited[j] == 0) {
                    visited[j] = 1;
                    st.push(j);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception found");
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * The number of Isolated points
 *
 * @return ans
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
int numIsolatedPoints() throws IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    int i;
    int j;
    int ans = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            if (adjM[i][j] != -1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == nodes.size()) {
            ans++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

/**
 * Inclusiveness is the percentage of points in the graph that are not
 * isolated
 *
 * @return ((float)i)/nodes.size()
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
float inclusiveness() throws IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    int i = nodes.size() - numIsolatedPoints();
    return ((float) i) / nodes.size();
}

/**
 * Density of matrix
 *
 * @return (2*(float)noEdges)/(nodes.size()*(nodes.size()-1))
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
float density() throws IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    return (2 * (float) noEdges) / (nodes.size() * (nodes.size() - 1));
}



 public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalStateForMatrixException, ElementNotFoundException {
    AdjacencyGraph ag = new AdjacencyGraph();

    ag.addNode("A");
    ag.addNode("B");
    ag.addNode("C");
    ag.addNode("D");
    ag.createAdjacencyMatrix();
    ag.addEdge("A", "B", 5);
    ag.addEdge("A", "C", 2);
    ag.addEdge("B", "C", 1);
    ag.addEdge("B", "D", 2);
    ag.print();

    System.out.println("Num nodes:"+ag.getNumberOfNodes());
    System.out.println("Num edges:"+ag.getNumberOfEdges());

    System.out.println("Highest degree node = "+ag.getHighestDegreeNode());


    System.out.println("Cost of edge from A to B = "+ag.costOfEdgeBetween("A", "B"));
    System.out.println("Cost of edge from A to C = "+ag.costOfEdgeBetween("A", "C"));
    System.out.println("Cost of edge from B to C = "+ag.costOfEdgeBetween("B", "C"));
    System.out.println("Cost of edge from A to D = "+ag.costOfEdgeBetween("A", "D"));


    System.out.println("Has path from A to B = "+ag.hasPathBetween("A", "B"));
    System.out.println("Has path from A to C = "+ag.hasPathBetween("A", "C"));
    System.out.println("Has path from B to C = "+ag.hasPathBetween("B", "C"));
    System.out.println("Has path from A to D = "+ag.hasPathBetween("A", "D"));

    System.out.println("Number of isolated points is:  "+ag.numIsolatedPoints());
    System.out.println("Graph inclusiveness is: "+ag.inclusiveness());
    System.out.println("Graph density is: "+ag.density());
}
```

}

Comment: So what is your question? The code you show doesn't call `getHighestDegreeNode` nor `addEdge`. Do you want to know how to throw your own exception or do you want to know why you get the null pointer?

Comment: Both to be honest. I am unclear why I am getting these null pointer errors and I also am unsure on how to throw specifically the IllegalStateForMatrixException properly. I have attempted it, but just made the code even worse. Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: Ok, can you update your code with how you call the methods. You must have an object of the class `AdjacencyGraph` somewhere. Maybe in a `main` method? For the other part, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423700/how-to-create-a-custom-exception-type-in-java)

Comment: My professor gave me a hint and said it was an easy fix, but im still unclear, this is what he said...                                                                        All you need to do is check the matrix has no positive values. If it doesn't throw the IllegalStateForMatrix Exception. 

You can also set a boolean value to false and when you call createMatrix set it true. This will be a way to check if createMatrix was called before or after addEdge. Then checking in addEdge you can throw the exception.

Comment: I added my main method for you. Thanks again Stefan!

Comment: Can you please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I dont see why you get the `NullpointerExceptions` and cant reproduce it. The boolean value your prof talked about should be a class variable that is initialy false and when you call `createMatrix` you set it to true.