# How to use jUnit 5 Assertions to check, whether exception message starts with a String?

Tags: java, exception, junit, junit5, assertion

I use `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions` object to assert an exception is thrown:

```
Assertions.assertThrows(
        InvalidParameterException.class,
        () -> new ThrowingExceptionClass().doSomethingDangerous());
```

Simplified, the exception thrown has a variable part `dateTime` in its message:

```
final String message = String.format("Either request is too old [dateTime=%s]", date);
new InvalidParameterException(message);
```

As of version I use `5.4.0` the [`Assertions`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html) provide three methods checking the exception is thrown:

- [`assertThrows​(Class<T> expectedType, Executable executable)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable))
- [`assertThrows​(Class<T> expectedType, Executable executable, String message)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable,java.lang.String))
- [`assertThrows​(Class<T> expectedType, Executable executable, Supplier<String> messageSupplier)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable,java.util.function.Supplier))

Neither of them provides a mechanism checking whether a String **starts with** another String. The last 2 methods only check whether the String is equal. How do I check easily whether the exception message starts with `"Either request is too old"` since more message variations might occur within the same `InvalidParameterException`?

---

I'd appreciate a method `assertThrows​(Class<T> expectedType, Executable executable, Predicate<String> messagePredicate)` where the predicate would provide the thrown `message` and the assertion passes when if predicate returns `true` such as:

```
Assertions.assertThrows(
    InvalidParameterException.class,
    () -> new ThrowingExceptionClass().doSomethingDangerous()
    message -> message.startsWith("Either request is too old"));
```

Sadly, it doesn't exist. Any workaround?

Comment: @Didier L: Thanks for finding the dupe :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `assertThrows()` method **returns** an exception instance of the expected type (if any). You can then manually get a message from it and check if it starts with the string you desire.

Here is a sample from [doc](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.2/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions)

```
@Test
void exceptionTesting() {
    Exception exception = assertThrows(ArithmeticException.class, () ->
        calculator.divide(1, 0));
    assertEquals("/ by zero", exception.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice the `Assertions.assertThrows` returns the very same instance of the thrown exception. Thanks :)

Comment: If you want to check if actual message contains a substring use following in JUnit5 ```MatcherAssert.assertThat("should contain expected message", actualException.getMessage(), containsString("<desired substring goes here>"));```

Comment: Aaaand… that’s a nice RTFM in my face! 

Answer (score 1):

You should test the content of the message text of an exception only if that message is a specified part of the API of the unit you are testing. But it is questionable whether you should do that.

The [message text of exceptions should not normally be presented to users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7320104/545127), as part of the UI of your application.

Specifying the content of the message text encourages clients of the API to parse that message text to learn specific information about the exceptional condition. This is tricky, error prone and unnecessary. In your case, clients might be tempted to parse the message text to extract the `date` value.

Instead, [create a custom exception type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423700/how-to-create-a-custom-exception-type-in-java) that more specifically describes the exceptional condition. In your case, you would want your custom exception class to extend `InvalidParameterException`. Your custom exception class could have a date field to make the additional data available. You unit test could check that the method under test throws an exception of the correct type, and that it has a date field with the correct value.

Comment: It's a bad-structured broad legacy code that I am not likely to refactor. I understand the reason behind your answer and we need the message of the exception for the log purposes. I only test whether a correct text is returned. Yet your answer is good, totally valid and I am aware of it, it doesn't solve the problem. Have my +1 anyway.